# How to fix an animation project from overuse of particles

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, blend-files

I am working on an animation and I have a scene where I needed to have one character blow snow at another character.  I tried using a particle system to do this, but I  made so many them blender became unresponsive.
I managed to deal with it at first, and when I was done with the work for a while I closed the animation and quit blender.  However, now when I try to open it it won't respond at all. How do i fix this?
I tried using the recover button but unfortunately it saved the blend file that was broken.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about it, but is your cache file still in place 
(can you move it somewhere else), maybe computer has a problem loading a huge cache file.

Another way of rescuing might be to create a new blend and import stuff from the other blend file that you like to rescue, if the file is really broken I'm afraid there are not many options left.